# Determine when reboot required after patching from the command line?

Tags: linux, ssh, reboot, yum, apt-get

After `ssh`'ing into a box and using `yum` or `apt-get` to patch, I would like to determine when a reboot is required. It would be incredibly helpful to know so we can schedule a reboot in a maintenance window.

Surprisingly, I did not find much reading on it. About the closest thing I found on a web search was [How do I know if a reboot is required after patching?](http://cloud.verizon.com/documentation/RebootAfterPatching.htm) from Verizon, which effectively stated Linux does not usually need it because programs restart themselves (I suppose it was written for the average consumer).

I know Linux GUI's offer it because, for example, the power button icon will turn red on Ubuntu/Unity. And I get prompted like below when logging in with a windows manager.

[image]

I regularly work with Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS and Red Hat, so its the reason I listed `yum` and `apt-get`.

How do I determine when a reboot is required after patching?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just have to know what got updated and restart the appropriate services. For example, if OpenSSH was updated then you need to restart that service if you had it running at the time of the update.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure the GUI's "restart required" message is just because it can't reliably tell which files were updated and what services need to be restarted, so it asks for a complete machine reboot just as a precaution, but besides when updating the kernel, the `init` daemon (such as systemd) or some low-level library which everything depends on, a full system reboot isn't necessary.

Comment: @André - why do I have to know? Or are you stating there's nothing standard, and each distro does its own thing (if they do anything at all). Also, Microsoft and Apple solved this years ago. Maybe my expectations of Linux are too high :)

Answer (score 3):

In Debian-based OSes, the package manager will create a file, `/var/run/reboot-required`, if a patch requires a reboot. This file is deleted when the machine is restarted. See [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28530/how-can-i-tell-what-package-requires-a-reboot-of-my-system) for more information about how to determine which package required a reboot.

To get the same functionality in `yum`, it appears that you need to install a [third-party plugin](https://github.com/stdevel/yum-plugin-needs-restarting).

Comment: Thanks @ncdownpat. If you know Red Hat/Fedora/Cent, then please share it and I'll award the Answer and put the question to bed. Otherwise, I should probably leave it open for a while.